# Web site administration tool - Create admin user

Tags: asp.net

How can I create a user as an administrator using web site administration tool?

Answer (score 0):

[First create the roles you need](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssa0wsyf.aspx), like administrator, under the security tab. Then go to the users tab and there you can create new users and assign them to a role.